# How to make a reusable table component which can handle different data structures and layouts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building an app with many tables. Generally they look the same, but some has different columns set or cell content. I'd like to make a reusable table component which can be used through out the entire app.

At the moment I made a table wrapper component which accepts children and table type. Columns are rendered depending on table type. Then I have several components each for different table because data structure may differ and layout might be slightly different. The question is how to make a single table component which can handle different data structures and different layouts?

I think it can be done with conditional rendering (but I do not want excessively use this because it will be hard to maintain and difficult to read):

```
  {tableType === "first" ? <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell> : null}
  {tableType === "second" ? <TableCell>{item.status}</TableCell> : null}
```

I was told that it can be done in somekind of this way:

```
<TableCell>{getCellComponent(tableType, value)}</TableCell>
```

Unfortunatelly I'm not that smart enough to make it myself. I understand the general idea for this approach but don't understand how to make it. Can someone help me with that please?

I made a Codesandbox with two simplified tables:
https://codesandbox.io/s/complex-table-yrrv6c?file=/src/App.tsx

**UPD**

I went with @Dilshan solution. It works great. Meanwhile there're couple TS errors which I don't know how to fix.

I want to store `columns` props in a variable. Like this:

```
const columnObj = {
  firstName: {
    name: "First Name",
    width: "25%",
    accessor: (payload: any) => (
      <>
        <Avatar />
        {payload.who.nickname}
      </>
    )
  },
  // ...
};
```

**But then what type should I specify for payload?**

I'd like to pass `onClick` handler to the table. Basically I want whole row to be clickable:

```
  <MyTable<PayloadTyep2>
    columns={columnObj}
    payload={secondTableData}
    onClick={(id) => console.log("Row clicked:", id)}
  />
```

Then in assign it in Table component:

```
  <TableBody>
    {payload.map((rowData, index) => {
      return (
        <TableRow key={index} 
         onClick={(id) => props.onClick(rowData.id)}> // here get TS error
          // ...
        </TableRow>
      );
    })}
  </TableBody>
```

**How to fix that?**

Here's forked Codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-reusable-table-forked-vk7h6o?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets think about your requirement. You need to render a table based on given data payload. Table needs to know what's it columns. We can provide columns as a n input as well,

```
<MyTable
  data={myData}
  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
/>
```

We can assume `col1`, `col2`, `col3` are keys of the `myData` object so the `MyTable` components can now extract the cell data by simply doing `myData[columns[i]]` where `i` is the index of column array item.

Based on your mock data, I can see there are nested objects in your data as well. Therefore simple `myData[columns[i]]` is not going to work. As a solution we can provide a function to return cell value in the component props.

```
type TableProps<T extends object> = {
  columns: Record<
    string,
    {
      name: string;
      width: string;
      accessor: (data: T) => ReactNode | string | undefined;
    }
  >;
  payload: T[];
};

export const MyTable = <T extends object>(props: TableProps<T>) => {}
```

As you can see `accessor` is a function which has one argument `type T` which returns a React element or string or nothing.

Now in the table component we can simply do,

```
<TableRow key={index}>
 {Object.keys(columns).map((key) => {
   const { accessor } = columns[key];
   return (
     <TableCell key={key} align="left">
       {accessor(rowData)}
     </TableCell>
   );
 })}
</TableRow>
```

Then when you use the Table component,

```
      <TableWithTitle<PayloadType1>
        columns={{
          phone: {
            name: "Phone",
            width: "14%",
            accessor: (payload) => payload.phohe
          },
          notes: {
            name: "Notes",
            width: "14%",
            accessor: (payload) => {
              return payload.notes?.map(({ note }) => note).join(", ");
            }
          }
        }}
      ....
```

Here is a full code [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-reusable-table-pc9vdp?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you take a look at UPD to help me fix TS errors?

Comment: Where do you see the TS errors ? You mean the `columnObj` doesn't have intelisens ? [updated](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-reusable-table-forked-uj6ghp?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Don't do `onClick={(id) => props.onClick(rowData.id)}` because that reduces the reusability of your Table component as this adds a constraint on input data which is every object of input data array must have an id field type number. Instead just provide the whole rowPayload so from parent component you can do whatever you want, `onClick={(id) => props.onClickRow(rowData)}`

Comment: However, if you don't want to pass whole payload & just need to do `props.onClick(rowData.id)}`, you can change `payload: T[];` to `payload: (T & {id: number})[];`

Comment: Thanks you help a lot. May I ask last question? I will have a progress bar in some tables (not in all tables). The progress data (1, 2, 3 ... 100%) will come from websockets. I'm not going to store progress values in payload obj ( I mean in table data mock-object). I'm going to get progress data in a component where I use Table component and pass it as a prop like I do with onClick. The question is how to pass this progress value to a cell where I use linear progress component?

Comment: You can do it as it done with the profile cell. Simply you can return your custom progress bar component from `accessor: () => <MyCustomProgressBar />`. You can implement the "Get Progress data" functionality within `<MyCustomProgressBar />`

Comment: My question was about another thing. Sorry for misleading. Please take I look at Codesandbox, I added comments in App.tsx: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-reusable-table-forked-vk7h6o?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: You can use context for do socket related work, then do like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-reusable-table-forked-81dh2w?file=/src/tables.tsx).  If you do have more questions please post them as separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example for your reference:

First you may define columnList object:

```js
 let columnList = [
        { label: "Post", accessor: "post" },
        { label: "Name", accessor: "name" },
        { label: "Email", accessor: "email" },
        { label: "Primary Phone No", accessor: "primaryPhoneNo" },
        { label: "Secondary Phone No", accessor: "secondaryPhoneNo" }
    ]

    <DataTable
    columnList={columnList}
    dataList={staffList}
    ......../>
```

where
dataList is an array of data,
the label field of the `columnList` object is store the column label,
and the accessor is the field name in dataList.

In DataTable component,

```js
export default function DataTable({
  columnList,
  dataList
}) {
return(
<table >
    <thead>
    <tr> {
      columnList.map((column, index) => ( 
      <th> {
          column.label
        } 
      </th>
      ))
    } 
    </tr>
    </thead>      
    <tbody> {
      dataList.map((data) => ( 
        <tr >
        columnList.map((column, colIindex) => ( 
          <td > {
            data[column.accessor]
          } </td>  
        ))
        </tr>
      ));
    } 
    </tbody> 
    </table>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to make code less fragile to changes, i.e everytime you add a new table type or make changes to existing table, the affect on other table types should be minimum, you can read more about SOLID principles later.

use composition to make component more reusable

There is a basic idea of the solution

```
// create a factory/config to pick the right header columns based on type
const tableOneColumnHeaders = [
  { id: 1, name: "First name", width: "25%" },
  { id: 2, name: "Second name", width: "16%" },
  { id: 3, name: "Address", width: "14%" },
  { id: 4, name: "Phone", width: "14%" },
  { id: 5, name: "Notes", width: "14%" }
];

const tableTwoColumnHeaders = [
  { id: 1, name: "First name", width: "25%" },
  { id: 2, name: "Status", width: "16%" },
  { id: 3, name: "Author", width: "14%" },
  { id: 4, name: "Date", width: "14%" },
  { id: 5, name: "Media", width: "14%" },
  { id: 6, name: "Rating", width: "14%" },
  { id: 7, name: "Project", width: "14%" },
  { id: 8, name: "", width: "3%" }
];

// poor mans factory
const headerColumnsFactory: headerType = {
  [TableType.FirstTable]: tableOneColumnHeaders,
  [TableType.SecondTable]: tableTwoColumnHeaders

};

// create a row renderer factory/config to pick the right renderer
// each table has a custom body renderer
const TableOneRowsMapper = (props: { data: RowData[] }) => {
 const { data } = props;

  const rows = data as FirtTableDataType[];

  return (
    <>
      {rows?.map((item) => (
        <TableRow key={item.id}>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {item.name}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="left">{item.address}</TableCell>
   ...



const TableTwoRowsMapper = (props: { data: RowData[] }) => {
  const { data } = props;

  const rows = data as SecondTableDataType[];

  return (
    <>
      {rows.map((item) => (
        <TableRow key={item.id}>
          <TableCell
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              direction: "row",
              gap: "5px",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Avatar />
            {item.who.nickname}
...



const TableBodyRowsComponentFactory = {
  [TableType.FirstTable]: TableOneRowsMapper,
  [TableType.SecondTable]: TableTwoRowsMapper
};
```

/

```
/ A component that uses the factories to pick the right renders and render the table

const ExtensibleTable = (props: {
  title: string;
  type: TableType;
  data: any[];
}) => {
  const { title, type, data } = props;

  // if a switch of if is used, this code becomes fragile

  /*
     // with introduction of new if else or modification of existing if
     // othe tables types can break because of shared variable etc
     if (type === '') {
        return  some columsn
     } else if ( type === 'xy') {

     }

 */

  //  but with a bulder the right components are picked
  //  and changes to each type of component are seperated
  //  new ones can be added without affecting this common code
  // pick the right header columns
  const headerColumns: HeaderRowType[] = React.useMemo(
    () => headerColumnsFactory[type] ?? [],
    [type]
  );

  // pick the right row renderer
  const RowRenderer = React.useMemo(
    () => TableBodyRowsComponentFactory[type] ?? TableEmptyRenderer,
    [type]
  );

  return (
    <BaseTable
      title={title}
      headerRow={
        <TableRow>
          {headerColumns.map(({ name, id, width }) => (
            <TableCell align="left" width={width} key={id}>
              {name}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      }
    >
      <RowRenderer data={data} />
    </BaseTable>
  );
};


const BaseTable = (props: IBaseTableProps) => {
  const { title, children, headerRow } = props;

  return (
    <Stack
      gap={"20px"}
      alignItems={"center"}
      sx={{ background: "lightblue", padding: "20px", borderRadius: "20px" }}
    >
      <Typography variant="h3">{title}</Typography>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>{headerRow}</TableHead>
        <TableBody>{children}</TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

I had created a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/complex-table-forked-40qgd4?file=/src/App.tsx) with rest of the example

generally more usable the component becomes, less flexible it becomes

to reduce/handle such issues it helps to apply SOLID principles like [Inversion of Control](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/inversion-of-control)

I am not used to Typescript but I hope helps you in someway and gives you an general idea to make reusable compnents

Answer (score 0):

You can learn and refer to the "antd" Table Components.The component defined a amount of params to show different format content includes text,icon,image,tree even a table.